# Stored procedure execution results in error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our system has a stored procedure that can create a Crystal Report of the output of the query.

When I execute it, I get this error:

> HR = 0x80070005 Source = ODSOLE Extended Procedure Description = Access is Denied

Comment: This is a Windows permission error.  I'm guessing the stored proc saves the report in a folder?  Do you have write permission on this folder?

Comment: Okay I'll try to check my permissions on the output folder